# Ethernet RFID reader not connecting to PC

Tags: networking, ip, ethernet

I have purchased a ACM812a RFID reader and want to connect it to my PC via an ethernet cable. I thought it would just be a plug and play application but it is rather becoming a frustrating issue. The RFID reader manual or lack of there of, doesn't provide an IP address for the reader. So I have researched that I can use Winshark to ascertain the IP address of the reader. However even this software fails to extract the IP address of the reader, see picture below. The IP address of the computer is 169.254.106.15.

[image]

The reader application is shown in the picture below. From the picture, you can see the application requires an IP address and a port number. Can someone please help to get the IP address of the reader and how to get the port number so I can run the RFID reader application? (The 6000 port no. and 192.168.1.192 IP address is just a dummy that default when the application opens).

The reader RJ45 connector has 4 wires connecting to the RJ45 connector and my ethernet cable connecting the reader to the PC as 8 wires. Is this also an issue?

The model of the router is: B315s - 936 Huawei

[image]

Pictures of reader:

[image]

Comment: Plug both computer and RFID into the router, not each other. Check the router DHCP leases in the webUI, there you should find your device Mac and whatever IP it was assigned. Once you know the IP address you can use nmap to see what ports are open on it

Comment: @Tim_Stewart will this also give me the port number to use?

Comment: Note the "COM" and "TCP/IP" selector top left. Make sure to set it correctly (COM is likely to be a Virtual COM-port setup, which is likely to need an appropriate driver installed). In my eyes; the default IP is an indication to use "192.168.1.x" for the network segment where you connect it *initially* (with TCP/IP, selected! It would likely NOT have any effect with COM selected).

Comment: @Tim_Stewart could you tell me what exact info for the reader you need. In terms of the initial setup, there's absolutely no instruction for this. I should have done more research before buying this reader. I would appreciate if you could guide with a step by step instructions. Thank you!

Comment: @Hannu I tried 192.168.1.101 and 255.255.255.0 and still not working, this is by far the most disappointing rfid package I have bought to date. Shows what happens when you buy cheap tech.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart "Check the router DHCP leases in the webUI, there you should find your device Mac and whatever IP it was assigned" I have a Huawei router where do I find the DHCP leases?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart hi thanks for getting back. I have added the model number.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart that is really gracious of you! I did not expect this level of assistance, kind of amazed. When I connect my other desktop to the same router via ethernet, I can see the IP address of the desktop computer on my laptop using the ipconfig on the command prompt. This shows the router is working and the ethernet ports. So I am amazed why the router is not assigning an IP address to the RFID reader when its connected to it via ethernet.

Comment: What do you get with them both plugged into the router typing **ARP -a** at the command prompt? Most versions of windows it's **start > type cmd > [enter]** to bring up the command prompt. Btw their support told me they do not have a full featured manual for it, just the quick start guide. :/

Comment: @Tim_Stewart The ARP -a command only gives the IP address of the router, when the RFID reader and desktop is plugged into the router. When I connect the other desktop and run the same command the command returns the IP address of the router and the other desktop and still not the reader.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I also connected another RFID reader that supports TCP/IP and that also is not picked up.

Comment: Hmm, that's odd. If it's assigned an IP it should be in the ARP table. You can try scanning the whole network IP range with Nmap. It it doesn't come up, I must admit I'm running out of ideas for you. https://www.networkstraining.com/nmap-scan-ip-range/

Comment: @Tim_Stewart running the scan. If it does not come up, does it mean the reader is not actually TCP/IP or could my system not be compliant? The command I use is nmap  192.168.8.1-245, is this right?

Comment: @Tim_Stewart the router ip is 192.168.8.1. Shouldnt 192.168.1.0/24 be 192.168.8.0/24?

Comment: It's" 192.168.1-254" or just "192.168.1.0/24". Good question, is it showing a link light when you plug it in? I'm starting to wonder if it's designed for Ethernet at all, I've installed proprietary RFID systems that used rj-45 for installation convenience, but need to go back to some sort of controller for them, that then interfaced with an Ethernet network. I'm not finding very much documentation for that reader unfortunately

Comment: @Tim_Stewart so I ran the scan using the ACM812a reader and also a ZKTeco u1000e reader. There is info on the ZKTeco reader. Still the nmap is still not detecting the both readers. The ACM812a rj45 connector is showing a green light when power is applied and a orange light does blink sometimes. The ZKTeco connector does not have a light.

Comment: Bad news, that model doesn't support Ethernet. I'll write up an answer shortly for you on how to connect to it, or weigh up the decision not to use it. I would recommend the latter if you have more than a couple to install

Comment: @Tim_Stewart thank you. I saw the documentation for the ZKTeco reader and it shows it does support TCP/IP. I am just really confused why this reader (ZKTeco) does not also work.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart I have added the pic.

Comment: @Tim_Stewart could show me how its suppose to work, when you used a similar RFID reader. Even if it doesn't answer my question I would like to see and gain insight of how its actually done, and also so I don't waste my money buying stuff like this.